# Install Wechat Chinese version outside China

Tags: installation, wechat

Wechat has 2 versions, one for China (Weixin) and one for outside China (Wechat). I need some functions only available in the Chinese version.

How can I turn my international WeChat into a Chinese Wechat(Weixin) **from outside China**?

Comment: Based on quick research, AFAIK the app is the same, but the functions differ based on which account is used, [overseas phone number or (Chinese) domestic phone number](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248447/install-wechat-chinese-version-outside-china).